How to make a tied object be affected by the water current or be dragged along by the waves
Currently using Blender 4.2.3
I try to make objects that are tied so that they can be affected by water waves. For example, a rope tied and affected by filled water or waves.
Hope I make it clear. Thank you.

This is simply not possible with Blender's fluid simulation.
